# error while starting jboss 7.1

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

Unable to set property fileName on class org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureProperties(PropertyConfigurator.java:187)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureHandler(PropertyConfigurator.java:312)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:128)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:86)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:246)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:231)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:275)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\boot.log (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFile(FileHandler.java:152)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFileName(FileHandler.java:183)
    ... 20 more
20:48:27,119 INFOS [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS018704: Could not create server data directory: C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerEnvironment.(ServerEnvironment.java:388)
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.determineEnvironment(Main.java:242)
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:260)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:291)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Comment: JBoss AS 7.1 will not start successfully with Java 1.8.  [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/223739?start=0&tstart=0)  the forum thread of the issue.

If you really need to use Java 1.8 consider using WildFly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss AS 7.1 will not start successfully with Java 1.8. [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/223739?start=0&tstart=0)  the forum thread of the issue. If you really need to use Java 1.8 consider using WildFly
**And**  by pasting the new WildFly's directory  in the **C:/**